# How to tell Python to wait for Selenium?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I am able to filter the data with the code below but the Export to Excel does not work. I request your kind assistance on how to improve my snippet below to instruct Python to wait for the data to get fully loaded and then download the excel file to the desired folder.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Python27\Scripts\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://etrakit.friscotexas.gov/Search/permit.aspx")

number_option = driver.find_element_by_id("cplMain_btnSearch")
number_option.click()

delay = 3 
try:
     WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(driver.find_element_by_id("cplMain_btnSearch")))
    print "Page is ready!"
except TimeoutException:
    print "Loading took too much time!"


search_button = driver.find_element_by_id("cplMain_btnExportToExcel")
search_button.click()

options.add_argument("download.default_directory=C:\Users\Patrick\Desktop\Programming\R Files")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.close()
```

The Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Desktop\Programming\aspxscraping.py", line 14, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(driver.find_element_by_id("cplMain_btnSearch")))

 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 71, in until
value = method(self._driver)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 63, in __call__
return _find_element(driver, self.locator)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 328, in _find_element
return driver.find_element(*by)
 TypeError: find_element() argument after * must be a sequence, not WebElement
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace this

```
 WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(driver.find_element_by_id("cplMain_btnSearch"))
```

with this

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "cplMain_btnSearch")))
```

Comment: Thanks Anderson, that works for the code. Now it shows an error for Search.Button

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\aqureshi\Desktop\Programming\aspxscraping.py", line 22, in <module>
        search_button.click()

Comment: Add full exception log to your question and `HTML` code for search button

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
EC.presence_of_element_located(driver.find_element_by_id("cplMain_btnSearch"))
```

The point of the wait is to not try finding the element yourself, because it might not be there yet! It so happens that you found it in this case and the error is complaining about your use of `presence_of_element_located`. Here's what you need to do:

```
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "cplMain_btnSearch"))
```

See the docs: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits